# I cannot get the address and its balance even if I connected to the Metamask

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js, moralis

I am working on a dapp and I have a problem.
The problem is that even if I connected the Metamask to the dapp, I cannot get its balance. But, the most interesting part, I cannot see the address which is connected. I used moralis and ethers in the dapp. This is the code for balance:

```
const getBalance = async () => {
    const provider = await connectBlockchain()
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(STAKING_CONTRACT_ADDRESS)
    const balanceInEth = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)
    const finalBalance = (+balanceInEth).toFixed(4)
    setWalletBalance(finalBalance)
  }

 useEffect(() => {
    getBalance()
  }, [getBalance])
```

In this code account returns null

```
const { account } = useMoralis()
  console.log(account)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should log `account` from useMoralis in a useEffect. You can use `enableWeb3()` from useMoralis to connect your MetaMask account - this will then populate the `account` state. Also you can call getBalance() in the account useEffect if account is valid e.g. `if (account) getBalance()`.

Comment: I did what you said and it seems I cannot connect the contract in a right way, but it is strange that my wallet is connected to the dapp. What might be the reason? Should i check contract address or abi?

Comment: Yes make sure all of your parameters are correct.